# PHP variable doesn't shop up in HTML file

Tags: php, html, mysql, http, pdo

I'm trying to print the error message inside my login form if the username or the password is invalid. Everything works fine(user authentication, dbms connection...). If I print the message on my login.php file it shows up correctly, but when I want to print it on my html file it does not.

**HTML FILE: login.html.php**

```
<div class="login-form">
        <?php include __DIR__ . '/../backend/login.php'; ?>

        <form action="../backend/login.php" method="POST">
            <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your username" name="username" required>

            <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" id="passwordInput" placeholder="Enter your password" name="password" required>

            <input type="checkbox" onclick="rememberMeFunction()"> Show Password
            <p> <?php echo $error_message ?></p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit">


        </form>
    </div>
```

**PHP FILE: login.php**

```
<?php 

 include __DIR__ . '/../backend/functions.php';

 if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
$validation_result = validate_login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']); 

$error_message = " ";

if(!$validation_result){
    $error_message = "Username or password is invalid";
    header("location: ../frontend/login.html.php");
} else{
    header("location: ../frontend/login_success.html.php");
}
}
```

Comment: You set `$error_message` but then redirect to a different page where `$error_message` is not set. https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: How can I fix this? I want to get the error message and I want to redirect to the login page at the same time

Comment: Use sessions. That's the reason I posted that link

Comment: On a side note: your `for` attributes in your labels are wrong, they should match the `id` attribute of the referenced input element

Comment: Glad it works!!

Comment: But now whenever I load the login page, it shows up "Username or password is invalid". Is there a way to fix it with PHP or should I use Javascript?

Comment: Only show it when it's set (in PHP), and make sure to clear it (from the session) afterwards (in PHP)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line from your code

```
if(!$validation_result){
    $error_message = "Username or password is invalid";
    // -> header("location: ../frontend/login.html.php"); <- this line
} else{
    header("location: ../frontend/login_success.html.php");
}
```

Then add this line to your front code (login.html.php)

```
global $error_message;
if(!empty($error_message))
    echo $error_message;
```

Answer (score 0):

**I updated my p tag with this code:**

```
<?php 
      session_start();

      if(isset($_SESSION['error_message'])){
          $error_message = $_SESSION['error_message'];

            if(!empty($error_message)){
               echo $error_message;
               session_destroy();
            } 
      } 
?>
```

**It works! If the data I insert is wrong, the error message comes up. If I log in successfully and then I come back, the error message disappears. Same thing goes for when I go to the homepage and come back to the login page**